# Java application exception monitoring & alarms

Tags: notifications, snmp, alarms

We have a few applications which are running in Windows 2K, 2008 servers. They are written in java. 
These applications needs to do many automation tasks. We are having difficulty to monitor these applications. Sometime due to XYZ reasons application either hangs or fail to perform desired job. We only come to know about this after a few days when some one reports that desired function hasn't been executed. 
To come out of this issue, we added emails for each imp exceptions but then developer needs to spend time to check those 1000 emails everyday. Which is again not feasible & efficient solution.

Now we are looking for a alert, alarms, notification display & monitoring system. We need to have a remote application which can receive alarms from these java applications & then based on certain information/Condition/Configuration, remote application can display some red, orange, green text on the screen. Based on red text, users can be visually see that there is an issue in the system. If required users can be notified that there is a serious issue in the application.

Please help us to identify any existing mechanism, tool, package to achieve this goal. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are myriad ways to achieve this, but all of them will require some effort. Which way to proceed depends on your needs and abilities. A couple of options occur to me:

- Have your processes log their exceptions to a Syslog daemon, running on some central server. Then you could have an admin read through the log file for serious problems, but there are many ways to post-process syslog messages, a web search on it might give some more hints.
- Is there any way, when logged into the server, to observe whether or not the process is running properly or not? You could install something like Nagios on a sever, and write a plugin that monitors your particular process on all the servers. The plugin can basically be a shell script that checks "ps", or a log file, or whatever you want.
  If you are in an IT department, your organization might already have some system like this (NMS).
- I'm not sure why this question is tagged "snmp", but it's technically possible to install an SNMP agent on each server, and have them send traps on certain conditions. I do think it would be slightly overkill because you would also have to get a good SNMP manager to receive the traps and alert a sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a combination of the check_logfiles plugin to parse log exceptions and raise alerts, and check_jmx/jmxquery to check metrics inside the JVM such as heap usage and thread count.

[check_logfiles](http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/nagios/check_logfiles/)

[check_jmx](https://code.google.com/p/jmxquery/wiki/Usage)